# Dealing with data imbalance in a regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, classification, modeling

I'm working on a regression model that predicts (x,y) coordinates of points on a 2-d plot. The pink points are my actuals. We see that there are chunks of my actuals plot that are intentionally void of data, but my model is predicting values there (my few example blue prediction points).

Is there a way to train a regression model not to predict values in certain areas? Or to teach it: "if no actuals exist within (n,m) of predicted value, predict elsewhere"? Or, since I'm working with a relatively small dataset, will increasing my number of datapoints (though there will still be none in the voids) naturally improve this as the predictive power of my model increases?

[image: example plot]

I have considered first classifying points into distinct groups, as points in specific areas share some attributes, but I will end up with hundreds of classes and data voids and would prefer not to do this.

thanks!

Comment: For purely statistical methodology questions that do not involve a programming problem, please use https://stats.stackexchange.com (see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).